# What kind of encoding is this (sha256 variant)?

Tags: encoding, hashing, checksum

I have some config files from the program ELOG where I want to change the password manually, using something like `echo -n "newpassword" | sha256sum` but the value is not the expected hexa. Here's an extract from one such files:

```
<password encoding="SHA256">vyk1C6u3pcdfTIlvEFSdjvHBiymJBxUuvcZj3BR5Ol/</password>
```

What command can I use to generate a correct hash? This is not in the correct format:

```
$ echo -n "newpassword" | sha256sum
089542505d659cecbb988bb5ccff5bccf85be2dfa8c221359079aee2531298bb  -
```

The password `toto` gives the hash `bfvea3iDok9C0ptb022ndR2uWZUq0BIOH.cVQvSOMUA`

Comment: Why `-e`? *Maybe* all you need is `echo -n`.

Comment: Yes, it was -n, my mistake, but the question still stand, not sure why it was closed.

Comment: It is closed because we can only **guess** the command. If you told us what exact password `vyk1C6u3pcdfTIlvEFSdjvHBiymJBxUuvcZj3BR5Ol` corresponds to, then we could at least verify any single guess. If you told us what program uses the config files, then *maybe* we could find the documentation or analyze the source, or install the program and work with it to tell anything.

Comment: I tought it was some kind of common encoding I just didn't know. The program is `elog`, a logbook server. So I tested it and the password toto gives the hash "bfvea3iDok9C0ptb022ndR2uWZUq0BIOH.cVQvSOMUA"

Comment: @gronostaj It seems some salt is involved.

Comment: I've moved my comments moved to an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's raw SHA256 encoded with something base64-ish. The length matches base64 of 32 bytes without padding.

SHA256 produces a string of 32 bytes. This string is usually represented in the hexadecimal format (as 64 characters [0-9a-f]), but it's not a requirement. One may choose to use a different encoding to make the produced string shorter.

[Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) can encode any string of 8-bit bytes into a string that can be represented with ASCII characters with just 33% of length overhead (compared to 100% of overhead for hexadecimal).

Base64 is quite straightforward: it first converts the string of 8-bit bytes into bits, then splits this string into 6-bit bytes. These 6-bit bytes are then represented using a fixed alphabet consisting of, in this order:

- uppercase letters `A-Z` (26 values 000000..011001)
- lowercase letters `a-z` (26 values 011010..110011)
- digits `0-9` (10 values 110100..111101)
- characters `+` and `/` (111110, 111111)

for a total of 64 characters to represent all possible values of a 6-bit byte. The resulting string is padded with one or two `=` characters so that string length is a multiple of 4. Many implementations don't require the padding for decoding because it doesn't carry any information.

Your example hashes are 43 characters long. That length matches the length of non-padded base64 of a 32-byte string.

---

But it's not so simple with ELOG! By looking at the source code you'll find that [it uses a different base64 alphabet](https://bitbucket.org/ritt/elog/src/395e101add19f0fe8a11a25d0822e511f34d94d1/src/crypt.c#lines-324):

- characters `.` and `/`
- digits `0-9`
- uppercase letters `A-Z`
- lowercase letters `a-z`

This difference could be easily worked around by using `tr` to map these alphabets. But even then results don't match yet. In your example, the string `toto` produces the hash `bfvea3iDok9C0ptb022ndR2uWZUq0BIOH.cVQvSOMUA`. Note the two consecutive identical characters:

```
bfvea3iDok9C0ptb022ndR2uWZUq0BIOH.cVQvSOMUA
                 ^^
```

The string `toto` encoded with the 'regular' SHA256+base64 doesn't have these:

```
$ echo -n toto | sha256 | base64            
MfemXjFVhqwZi9eYtmKc5JA9CJlHbVdBqfMuLlIbamY=
                 ^^
```

A simple translation preserves similarity, so there must be something else at play here.

@KamilMaciorowski suggested in comments that some salt may be involved. A [cryptographic salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) is a randomized per-user string stored in plaintext that's appended to password before hashing so that identical passwords used by different users produce different hashes.

You can dive deeper into the code to figure out if the salt is used and how.

Comment: Thanks for the research. I'll have a look at the source code maybe some time to see about this salt. In the meanwhile I'll just create a temporary user from the user interface to generate a password hash.

Comment: i like explanation. clear ,short, consise